# Integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration

Use the substitution $u=\sin(4x)$ to find the exact value of $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{1}{24}\pi} \cos^3 4x \ \textrm{d}x$.

My steps:

$$u=\sin4x$$
$$u'=4\cos4x$$
$$dx=du/4cos4x$$
$$1/64(u')^{3}=cos^34x$$

What next? I'm stuck at this step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\cos^3(4x) = \cos^2(4x) \cos(4x) = (1-\sin^2(4x)) \cos(4x)$$
Now let $\sin(4x) = t$ and note that $4 \cos(4x) dx = dt$. I trust you can finish it off from here.

Answer (score 2):

This is not integration by parts. Having done the necessary substitution, perhaps suppress the limits for now and write
$$I=\int(\cos 4x)^3\cdot\frac{du}{4\cos 4x}=\frac14\int(\cos 4x)^2\,dx.$$

Do you know any relationship between $\cos^24x$ and $\sin^24x=u^2$?

Comment: $\cos^24x=1-\sin^24x$

Comment: You mean $\cos^24x=1-u^2$. So your integral no reads (with limits suppressed) 

$$\frac14 \int(1-u^2)\,du.$$

What do you do now? This is called a back-substitution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{24}}\cos^3 4x dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{24}}\cos^2 4x\cdot\cos4x dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{24}}(1-\sin^2 4x)\cdot\cos4x dx$$
$$=|\sin 4x=t\Rightarrow \cos4xdx=\frac{dt}{4}, x=0\Rightarrow t=0; x=\frac{\pi}{24}\Rightarrow t=\frac{1}{2}|$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-t^2)\cdot\frac{dt}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-t^2)dt=\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}dt-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}t^2dt\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left(t|_0^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{t^3}{3}|_0^{\frac{1}{2}})\right)=\frac{11}{96}$$